# Nodemailer is not able send mail using gmail

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am trying to send email through **nodemailer** but is not able to send email and showing following error.

```
{ [Error: Invalid login]
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsTr\n534-5.7.14 2r0PE8hXz57GMK9aydA3GouUGQr1Pc2wBywEf6i09kKVOv9Qv5y9Csy_lL-PIgUO6ML8uA\n534-5.7.14 ZsEiEkpAU0N5aiQBZdI1urKo3XfCiiS2MhjiUZaBgpn88sFXR-sBeA5ydMc_Md1F5wDcbX\n534-5.7.14 7ynrcVC-h0H_-e_ptvGhA3ywiHOSoDZAxzrindvEMNkXmCilbo9J7ITdlXFKwQjITaIkei\n534-5.7.14 Tk8QMKEY22ldNjE78Lh2ekheLd5M> Please log in via your web browser and\n534-5.7.14 then try again.\n534-5.7.14  Learn more at\n534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 21sm9309692qgj.21 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 534 }
```

I am using exact code as shown in nodemailer documentation.

this is server side code which i am using.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
       user: 'username',
       pass: 'password'
    }
});

app.post('/sendfeedbackmail', function(req, res) {

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Feedback<username@gmail.com>', // sender address 
        to: 'user1@gmail.com', // receiver 
        subject: 'Subject', // Subject line 
        text: mailData, // plaintext body 
        html: mailData // html body 
    };

   // send mail with defined transport object 
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
       if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          res.send({success:false});
       }else{
           res.send({
              success: true
           })
       }
   });
})
```

This was working fine few days ago and still working fine for other email client then gmail hence i think the issue may be related to any security setting of gmail account.

Comment: Have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451368/unable-to-send-html-text-using-nodemailer/38525491#38525491

Answer (score 7):

#### UPDATE

Check http://masashi-k.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html to register your application.

---

You will need something like this to authenticate on Gmail:

```
var xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtp = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var generator = xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
  user: '..',
  clientId: '...',
  clientSecret: '...',
  refreshToken: '...',
  accessToken: ''
});
generator.on('token', function(token){
  console.info('new token', token.accessToken);
  // maybe you want to store this token
});

var transporter_google = nodemailer.createTransport(smtp({
  name: '...',
  host: '...',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  ignoreTLS: false,
  tls: { rejectUnauthorized: true },
  debug: false,
  auth: { xoauth2: generator }
}));
```

See https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport#authentication.

Answer (score 5):

You may need to "[Allow Less Secure Apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)" in your gmail account (it's all the way at the bottom). You also may need to "[Allow access to your Google account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)". See details about using Gmail here.

Above solution worked for me which I found on github. Here's the [link](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/515).

Answer (score 0):

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
       user: 'username',
       pass: 'password'
    }
});
```

> Instead of  username = enter your valid email id and password = your password

again an alert shows to your **Gmail** from google like

> (Google will **continue to block sign-in attempts** from the app you're using **because it has known security problems or is out of date**. You can continue to use this app by **allowing access to less secure apps**, but this may leave your account vulnerable.
>   )

you need to allow the access from other mailer

then it generates the response