# unable to send html text using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I am unable to send html text in mail using nodemailer.

```
exports.send = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.query);
var mailOptions = {
    to: req.query.email,
    subject: req.query.sub,
    text: 'Date of Interview: ' + req.query.dateOfInterview+ 'Time of Interview: ' + req.query.timeOfInterview + '' + req.query.assignedTechnicalPerson + '' + req.query.typeOfInterview + '' + req.query.interviewLocation
}
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.end("error");
    } else {
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        res.end("sent");

    }
});
```

};

I am getting mail as continuous text without any line space 
How can i send the same text using html tags in it i have also tried keeping html and end up getting lots of errors

Please say me correct syntax

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use `email-templates-v2` to define the html template that can be used by nodemailer.

Comment: Can you add the error log as well. So that can figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working code with nodemailer latest version.

```
    var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
    var transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport(
        smtpTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: <Your gmail>,
                pass: '*****'//ur password
            }
        })
    );
    transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'sender@gmail.com',
        to: "recipient@mail.id",
        subject: 'hello world!',
        //text:"one"
        html: '<html><body>Hello World....</body></html>'
    }, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent');
        }
    });
```

**Note**:  To give access for smtp do the following:

1. For Gmail you may need to configure **"Allow Less Secure Apps"** in your
   Gmail account. [Click here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
2. You also may need to unlock your account with **"Allow access to your
   Google account"** to use SMTP.
3. If you are using 2FA in that case you would have to create an
   **Application specific password.**

Comment: `html` in `sendMail` arguments is the key here.

Comment: @ivosh I can't find any documentation on the requirement of `html` and `text` field in the `sendMail` function. Does nodeMailer automatically determine what kind of email to send or are they both being sent and rendered by the end user mail client?

Comment: I ran into this too.  the {{ body }} replacement shows raw markup encoded or decoded.

Comment: hint: solved this by just doing a `emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace('{{body}}', body);`.  That old template system was just injecting plain text.