# nodemailer is causing an error in production environment on Aws Ec2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-ec2, nodemailer

I am sending emails using `nodemailer` using `node.js` and i have this configuration to send emails

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            auth: {
                user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });
 const mailOptions = {
            from: 'myemail@gmail.com', // sender address
            to: user.company_email, // list of receivers
            subject: 'EnStream New Account Signup Password', // Subject line
            html: `<p style="font-size : 15px;">Please sing in to your en-stream account here <a href="http://demo.en-stream.com/auth/login">http://demo.en-stream.com/auth/login</a> with this password : ${userPassword}</p>`// plain text body
        };
```

It's sending emails on local environment correctly but in production environment on `Aws Ec2` it is throwing this error

```
code: "EAUTH"
command: "AUTH PLAIN"
response: "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbua↵534-5.7.14 qup7zOOL4GtmYEf1HEHBASSSBgbuMNJRQqK2v3X9mcxDRX1SrXU2Y_LSqZm7Y7yJvH2PwL↵534-5.7.14 JZW6iSXxsRhBdntFAAamrvitpdKS_YJiE-pEnXWakITAz1PAzwDMxjJPKntQrLl2Qx-xA1↵534-5.7.14 zZ4aTvKvYOAk85YHwABnnd0wHU2HkUeHPoDYqgXUWgSA_8Rrn4xkIsUN> Please log↵534-5.7.14 in via your web browser and then try again.↵534-5.7.14  Learn more at↵534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a11sm34494120wrx.5 - gsmtp"
responseCode: 534
```

I allowed outbound port 465 in my `ec2` instance security group like this

[image]

What's the real issue in this?

Comment: Have you checked error troubleshooting [steps](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=636911515684785996-1968142063&rd=2#cantsignin)?

Comment: Does this help? https://serverfault.com/questions/635139/how-to-fix-send-mail-authorization-failed-534-5-7-14

Comment: No. I have done these steps already and on my local machine it's working fine but on aws it's not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may require permission for this from Gmail.

For which you have to enable the [Allow access to your Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha).

Steps:

1. Go to this link through the same browser from which you are trying
   to Login.
2. It will ask "Allow access to your Google Account". Click on "Continue" button.
3. The message "Account access enabled" will be displayed.

Also, setting for "Less Secure Apps" must be allowed. Go through this link: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps.

If the issue still persists, check if your server IP is blocked by Gmail.

This should help!

Comment: Please refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493963/nodemailer-is-not-able-send-mail-using-gmail. This may help.

Comment: His problem is different from my problem and i also have different implementation of nodemailer. He did implementation using `xoauth2` but i have implemented using simple `nodemailer` with `http`.

Comment: My nodemailer worked after allowing access to the google account, thanks !