# Why am I getting a 500 error from NGINX Server on my EC2 instance React Express Node app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I can appreciate that this is quite a specific question, but I could really use some help because I am stuck for why this could be occurring.

I followed this [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@rksmith369/how-to-deploy-mern-stack-app-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-nginx-the-right-way-e76c1a8cd6c6) to upload my React / Express / Node app to AWS EC2.

You can see the Project Structure on Github. My server is in a different folder, but this shouldn't make a difference. [Link to Github](https://github.com/timiland/PersonalWebsite):

The front end works fine, and you can view it [here](http://3.138.194.248/).

It's the 'contact me' section at the bottom that I need to get to work. It links up with Nodemailer on the back-end to send me an email to my gmail.

Works fine in a development environment.

When I hit the api endpoint http://3.138.194.248/api/send with postman, I get back a message:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Something went wrong. Try again later"
}
```

Which I have set, so it would appear that the Express app is actually running.

I'm using pm2 and NGINX.

Environment variables are set up in a .env file in Ubuntu, exactly as they were in my development environment.

My NGINX config is as such

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://{{PRIVATE IP FROM EC2 INSTANCE}}:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Express app looks like so:

```
const path = require('path');

const cors = require('cors');

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client/dist');

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(buildPath));

app.use(cors());

const routes = require('./routes/api');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server start on port ${port}`);
})

app.use('/api', routes);
```

This seems to be giving me a 500 error in the console and it's not working anyhow.

Does anyone have some good troubleshooting steps that I can try or perhaps know why this might be happening?

Comment: That error is produced by `transporter.sendMail()` in line 40 of your api route. Try logging the error is generates rather than a generic error message to find out what is wrong. Maybe you haven't set up the env variables for gmail?

Comment: Try doing the following
1. Open port 465 in the outbound in the ec2 security config.
2. Set up the smtp server in the config like the following 
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: EMAIL_ID,
        pass: EMAIL_PASSOWRD,
    },
});

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606781/nodemailer-is-causing-an-error-in-production-environment-on-aws-ec2

Comment: I think this is an issue with Nodemailer on AWS. I have set up the outbound rules exactly as you suggest: "SMTPS TCP 465 0.0.0.0/0". I had already allowed less secure apps on Gmail, and I got a message from Gmail about an insecure sign in attempt as well. It's definitely not environment variables, because I've just typed the email and password in manually for the time being.